# Declaration merge doesn't work after publish as npm module

Tags: typescript

A class `AnyId` is defined in [core.ts](https://github.com/aleung/node-anyid/blob/db033cda40fcc5a0c9ab7b62b60a4a6e9509a2a0/src/core.ts).

In [time.ts](https://github.com/aleung/node-anyid/blob/db033cda40fcc5a0c9ab7b62b60a4a6e9509a2a0/src/time.ts) some more methods are added into it. I extend the type of `AnyId` using declaration merging:

```
declare module './core' {
  interface AnyId {
    time(unit?: TimeUnit): AnyId;
    since(t: Date): AnyId;
  }
}
```

It works fine in the [test case](https://github.com/aleung/node-anyid/blob/db033cda40fcc5a0c9ab7b62b60a4a6e9509a2a0/test/test-time.ts). Typing of additional methods `time` and `since` are available.

But after the module is published as npm module and being imported, declaration merge doesn't work:

```
import {anyid} from 'anyid';
anyid().encode('Aa0').time().since(new Date('2018-11-1'));
//                    ^^^^ error TS2339: Property 'time' does not exist on type 'AnyId'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaration merging done in `time.ts` is not visible when you import from published `anyid` module, because published `index.d.ts` does not reference `time` module at all.

Published `index.d.ts` contains only

```
import { AnyId } from './core';
declare function anyid(): AnyId;
export default anyid;
export {  AnyId, anyid };
```

The line in the source `index.ts` which imported `Time` from `./time` was elided by the compiler, because `Time` is not used as type in any of the declarations emitted in `index.d.ts`.

The easiest way to fix it is to add explicit reference to `time` in `index.ts`, [as recommended here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6835#issuecomment-178625549), or just re-export `Time`:

```
import { AnyId } from './core';
import { Time } from './time';
import { Random } from './random';
import { Fixed } from './fixed';
import { Sequence } from './seq';
import { Func } from './function';
import { Variable } from './variable';

export { Time } from './time';
```